# Heartbleed: length of heatbeat message?

Tags: heartbleed

What is the right length of heartbeat message between **2^14** and **2^16** ?

The RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6520 says that

> The total length of a HeartbeatMessage MUST NOT exceed 2^14 or
> max_fragment_length when negotiated as defined in [RFC6066].

In this [Heartbleed PoC](https://gist.github.com/sh1n0b1/10100394) the size is `40 00` in hex so 16 384 -> 2^14

But if I check these explanations (two from many):

http://stackabuse.com/article/how-to/how-to-exploit-the-heartbleed-bug
http://www.seancassidy.me/diagnosis-of-the-openssl-heartbleed-bug.html

Then the maximum length is 65 535 -> 2^16

**EDIT SOLVED ?**

I test Heartbleed PoC code, the hb code is :

```
hb = h2bin('''
18 03 02 00 03
01 40 00
''')
```

`40 00` -> 16 384 -> 2^14

If i print the length received, it show 16 384

If i replace `40 00` by `FF FF` -> 2^16, the length of the data received is still  16 384 four time.

```
16 384
16 384
16 384
16 384
```

=> 2^16

Interesting

**So the max is 2^16 but it will be divided on packets length 2^14**

Comment: The designed message length is 2^14, but there is overhead added to it (padding, etc)? Message is supposed to be one size, but to exploit it, you need the extra length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum size of a HeartbeatMessage (including padding, etc.) is **2^14** per [RFC 6520 sect. 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6520#section-4) as you pointed out.

OpenSSL however had an implementation issue that did not properly check for this bound (and allowing values up to the maximum size of an 16-bit integer, that is about **2^16**). The result is known as the "Heartbleed" bug. See [this OpenSSL commit](http://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=commitdiff;h=96db9023b881d7cd9f379b0c154650d6c108e9a3) for the fix which adds the missing boundary check.

If you are wondering why setting the payload length to 0xFFFF does not result in a single response of about 2^16 bytes, this is because the [maximum size for a TLSPlainText must not exceed **2^14**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246.html#page-19) which is also enforced in OpenSSL. (For a detailed explanation on the exact format for a crafted Heartbeat message, see [these comments of the pacemaker PoC](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/pacemaker/blob/master/pacemaker.py#L19).)

Comment: you mean 2^14 at the first line no ? rfc say `The total length of a HeartbeatMessage MUST NOT exceed 2^14`

Comment: @mpgn Yes you are right, amended the answer for that. Note that if you chose exactly `0xFFFF` as Heartbeat message length, you will not receive the last 19 bytes as these are being buffered.

Comment: the "pacemaker Poc" you wrote is really well explain ! i recommend to everyone to read it to understand the attack